# How to reset style for rich text in QML TextArea

Tags: qt, qml, richtext

If I insert rich text in QML TextArea, it will preserve that style (text color, underline etc.) for further inputs. Is there a way to prevent that from happening?

Example:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    TextArea {
        id: textArea
        textFormat: Qt.RichText
        focus: true
        selectByMouse: true
        selectByKeyboard: true

        Keys.onPressed: {
            if (event.text === "@") {
                textArea.text += "<a href='mentioned://user'>@User</a>";
                event.accepted = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I enter "@" character it will insert the `<a>` link instead, but when I continue typing other characters it will append them to the link, as if they are a part of it. How can I continue typing a new paragraph, without appending to the link ( tag)?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a whitespace after the tag solves the problem :

```
Window {
width: 640;
height: 480;
visible: true;
title: qsTr("Code from @Meliodas on StackOverflow");

    TextArea {
        id: textArea;
        textFormat: Qt.RichText;
        focus: true;
        selectByMouse: true;
        selectByKeyboard: true;

        Keys.onPressed: (event) => {
            if (event.text === "@") {
                // HERE
                insert(cursorPosition, "<a href='mentioned://user'>@User</a> ");
                event.accepted = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I took the freedom of modifying other pieces of your code :

- [insert()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-textarea.html#insert-method) instead of `text +=` to avoid automatic newlines
- explicitly defining `event` to silence a warning telling me implicit `event` parameters are deprecated

Comment: Thanks, but I've already tried that. It works fine if not touched, but if I press backspace to delete the space it will start appending to the url again. Also, if url is the first thing in the line and I go to the beginning of the line, it will prepend to the url once again. Is there a way to say "this is a finished tag, do not append/prepend any new text to it, rather type as plain text"?

Comment: `TextArea` is meant for it's contents to be editable, but there's probably some hacky workaround using the length of the text, or some HTML attribute. Really think through what you are trying to do before you make your life too complicated and end up having unclean code, going against the purpose of something rarely ends well

Comment: Yeah, I understand what you are saying. I tried various other things, using QTextCursor interface via QTextDocument, but none of the building blocks (blocks, frames, fragments, lists) were what I needed. Also, I tried generating and inserting image, but it didn't work out as I wanted.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want the tags to be non-editable ?

Comment: They are supposed to be chat mention tags, so for example, if I mention you in a message "Hey @Oxymore-coder did it work?" I want the inserted <a> link to only contain your name, to prevent user from editing it to "Hey #Oxymore-coder-fake did it work?" since that is not a valid username. Of course, one could detect that tag is broken and treat it as plain text, but I would rather have non-editable tags.

Comment: What comes to mind would be to have just plain text inputted, some kind of submit button, and some code to parse all special chars (like your '@'), then append the parsed form to some element containing each draft, a bit like Stackoverflow